# Get information about cpu-usage in Java

Tags: java, cpu, cpu-usage

hope you can help me with my problem. I need to get information about cpu/ram usage of an algorithm implemented in Java. There is method to do that?

Comment: you might want to look into so-called Profilers for Java. Examples are YourKit, JProfiler, VisualVM, Java Flight Recorder, ...

Comment: Can you please set an example?

Comment: Turn on `-XX:+NativeMemoryTracker` this will show u the memory the whole JVM is consuming. Then try JMX bean to retrieve CPU time

Answer (score 0):

You can get approximations of memory usage using the `java.lang.Runtime` class.

As comments have suggested, though, you're better off using a profiling application, such as Java VisualVM which comes bundled with the JDK (as of version 6, update 7); assuming you're using Windows, find it as *jvisualvm.exe* in the *bin* directory of your JDK installation. JVisualVM will allow you to monitor the CPU and Heap usage, among many other resources, of any running instance of Java.